# Cannot find reference - package and inner package with same name

Tags: python, pycharm

I've just started working on some big project and I faced the problem with referencing the right file from the package. The structure looks like:

```
root
  ├ test
  |  └__init__.py
  |  └foo
  |    └__init.py
  |    └test
  |      └__init__.py
  |      └bar.py 
  └ main.py
```

There's a single method called foo() in the bar.py file. In the main.py there's import like:

```
from test import bar

test.foo()
```

and as I know people were running this app and working on it for a long time. As I know they weren't using PyCharm. As I loaded the project into PyCharm it has shown me an error

```
Cannot find reference 'bar' in '__init__.py
```

Is there any solution to set up the PyCharm to run it?

Comment: `from test import bar` will only import the symbol `test.bar` as `bar` as opposed to `import test` which will import `test.bar` as `test.bar` as well as other symbols in test as `test.othersymbol`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I've checked the solution in this big project and it is the same as the structure I've shown. It doesn't run so I wonder how they did they configure it.

Comment: Are there any hidden imports in `__init__.py` files?

Comment: No, there aren't